# Excel, identify unique items

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create an additional column in an existing table. This new column is an identifier if the row is unique.

Here is a screenshot. Please help me write a formula in column C which gives the result as displayed here:

- blank if it is duplicated.
- 1 to be displayed if it is its first instance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `COUNTIFS` with mixed references:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2)>1,"",1)
```

[image]